# $L^2$-inner product of two functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider the space $C(0,π) := \{f : [0,π] → R;f\text{ continuous}\}$ equipped with the $L^2$- inner product. Let $f(x) =\sin x$, $g(x) = x^{2}$

How do we find the norm of $f$ and $g$ ? 
To check if $f$ and $g$ are orthogonal do we calculate 
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}x^{2}\sin x dx ?$$

I got $2x\sin x-(x^2-2) \cos x+constant$ which is not $0$ hence not orthogonal , is this correct?

Comment: You should be doing definition integral instead of indefinite integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John is right, you need to use definite integrals. Do we want the norms or their inner product? The inner product is
$$(f|g)_{L^2}=\int_0^\pi x^2\sin x\ \mathrm{d}x=\pi^2-4$$
so they are not orthogonal. To find their respective norms we have
$$\|f\|_2=\left(\int_0^\pi |x^2|^2\ \mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/2}=\left(\frac{\pi^5}5\right)^{1/2}=\frac{\pi^{5/2}}{\sqrt{5}}$$
and
$$\|g\|_2=\left(\int_0^\pi\sin^2x\ \mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/2}=\left(\frac\pi2\right)^{1/2}=\sqrt{\frac\pi2}$$

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to substitute the boundaries sorry.